# java regex involving positive lookbehind and lookahead

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to figure out a regex for to find `<ANYTHING_BUT_WHITSPACE>?` OR `?<ANYTHING_BUT_WHITSPACE>` and replace the ? with a blank space.

So,
'?test test?'  should become 'test test'

Below is the regex i came up with; but doesnt seem to work. Any suggestions?

```
s.replace("(?<=/S)?|?(?=/S)", "");
```

- (?<=/S)? look for ? with positive look-behind of anything but whitespace (\S)
- | or
- ?(?=/S) look for ? with positive lookahead of anything but whitespace (\S)

Comment: Maybe **[`.replaceAll("\\?(\\S+)|(\\S+)\\?", "$1$2");`](http://ideone.com/h4bmMQ)**?

Comment: `?` has special meaning in a regex, so to match a literal `?` you need to escape it using `\\?`. `/S` should be `\\S`. So in all, like this: `"(?<=\\S)\\?|\\?(?=\\S)"`. See [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hX4iJ5/1) for demo.

Comment: `Any suggestions?` Yeah, usually besides the obvious syntax errors, folks offer an example of what not to do. Using a leading assertion in any alternation with a construct like `\S`, makes a normal match slower by a factor of up to 20 times. Assertions are independent and can't be optimized. You don't seem to care. -1. So this comment is left for any reader that may land on this question.

Comment: @sln thanks for the comment. Please let me know if you're aware of any links/resources explaining this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to escape the question mark if used as a literal in regex
expression because it is a metacharacters.

So, it's probably this you need

```
 (?:
      (?<! \s )
      \?
   |  
      \?
      (?! \s )
 )
```

However, it may not look intuitive, but using an expression with a *leading*
assertion greatly slows down the engine.

To get better results, match the literal first then check with an assertion.

```
 \?
 (?:
      (?! \s )
   |  (?<! \s \? )
 )
```

Let's compare the relative performance using [Benchmark](http://www.regexformat.com/scrn7/s7_b4.jpg) software.

Input

```
wrgasgsagasf?afbafbadfbadfbadfbafdb
dddd? asfbasbfasfb
?asvgasgasgasgasg
```

Bench

```
Regex1:   \?(?:(?!\s)|(?<!\s\?))
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   3
Elapsed Time:    0.15 s,   154.76 ms,   154756 µs


Regex2:   (?:(?<!\s)\?|\?(?!\s))
Options:  < none >
Completed iterations:   50  /  50     ( x 1000 )
Matches found per iteration:   3
Elapsed Time:    0.89 s,   894.83 ms,   894834 µs
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all your regex have some mistakes. You used `/` instead of `\`. Second thing is escaping the characters.

The regex you are looking for is `(?<=\S)\?|\?(?=\S)` and replace with `empty`
 string.

**Note:** For Java use double escapes i.e `\\S` and `\\?`.

### <kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kC2dD4/2)**</kbd>

Comment: No need to put `\S` inside a character class (`[]`). It's already a character class.

Comment: Your answer worked (after adding escapes), also as Andreas mentioned no need to put \S inside a character class ([]). This code s = s.replaceAll("(?<=\\S)\\?|\\?(?=\\S)", "") worked perfectly. Since Andreas does not have an answer, i will go ahead and accept yours. Thanks.

Comment: @N.M.: As I was giving demo on Regex101.com I missed adding double escape. Updated now.

Comment: @N.M.: Please accept an answer only when you are sure it solves your problem. Do not switch accepted answers in future. It creates confusion and discredit to author.

Comment: I don't think there is a rule on changing votes. There is certainly not any _do nots_ on SO that I know of that have to do with votes. Clarity defeats confusion, authors are meaningless.

Comment: @sln: I didn't said there is any **Rule**. It's like you accept a solution. People use that one and then you suddenly change the accept vote. I mean **Are you kidding ?** If it's not clear then OP should not accept solutions so soon. That was my point and obviously you missed that.

Answer (score 0):

- First the `?` as a literal needs to be escaped since it is special regex character  (`\\?` instead of `?`).
- You should use `replaceAll` instead of `replace` to replace using a regex.
- Also make sure to re-assign the return value of `replaceAll` to a string because strings are immutable in Java.
- The non-whitespace predefined character group is `\S` not `/S`.